# ¿Quién envía el parámetro de props a TodoList?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo este componente en react:

```js
import react from "react";

function TodoList(props) {
  return (
    <section>
      <ul>{props.children}</ul>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comprendo que `{props.children}` me devuelve lo que está contenido en `{props.children}`. Ahora mi pregunta es ¿por qué a TodoList se le pasa el parámetro de props y quién se las envía? ¿Es necesario pasar a TodoList el parámetro de props, si en react cuando una "etiqueta" está abierta y luego cerrada ya genera la propiedad children por defecto, solo llamándola entre llaves ya retorna el dato que contenga...? ¿Es realmente necesario pasarle a TodoList el parámetro de props? Estoy un poco confundido...

Comment: Todo eso sucede dentro del `render` interno de `react`. entonces esa propiedad se la pasa react. Es necesario usar `props` para poder llamar a `children` dado que ahí fue almacenada. Si tienes más dudas, creo que debe ser más específico, ya que tus dudas son un poco generales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En teoría general, cada componente de React es una función que recibe datos de entrada a los que se les conoce como `props` y dicha función retorna elementos de react que basicamente van a describir lo que debería aparecer en la pantalla

Básicamente estas `props` son la colección de datos que un componente recibe

- **De quien? -> del contenedor padre**
- **Para que? -> Para ser usado para definir los elementos que retornara el componente**

Ejemplo de un caso de uso de tu componente

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <TodoList>Hello</TodoList>
    </div>
  );
}
```

En el codigo de arriba es `App` el componente padre y TodoList el componente Hijo por ende el padre pasa las propiedad a su hijo.

- El componente Hijo necesita declarar `props` para acceder a dichas propiedad.

---

En respuesta a tu pregunta:

> Si en react cuando una "etiqueta" esta abierta y luego cerrada ya
> genera la propiedad chidren por defecto

La propiedad children vive en los datos que se pasan en el objeto `props`, no accedes a ellos de manera mágica solo llamándolos directamente en tu componente hijo

```
<TodoList>Hello</TodoList>

{children: "Hello"}
children: "Hello"
<prototype>: Object
```

Una etiqueta abierta y una cerrada sin nada dentro de ella no genera una propiedad children:

```
<TodoList></TodoList>

{}
<prototype>: Object
```

**El parámetro props es obligatorio?**

No, mientras tu componente no necesite algunas de las propiedad contenidas en dicho objetos.

Ejemplo

```
function TodoList() {
  return (
    <section>
      <ul>Hello</ul>
    </section>
  );
}
```